# OpenCV: How to remove text from specific part of a black and white image

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract

Good morning.

I am developing an application in `Python` to detect the frames of a manga page, and that detects the speech bubbles to erase the text. Example:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qeut0.jpg):
1st Image:

[image]

[image]

Ideal result 1:

[image]

However, `OCV` has difficulties to detect the text formed in Japanese or Korean, so I thought that perhaps it was easier to find an algorithm that recognized the shape of the speech bubbles and filled their interior with white, eliminating the text.

I would also like to divide the manga pages by their frames, although this is much simpler, because they are usually square and have a frame that makes them easily detectable.

The problem is that I dont have much idea about `OCV or Tesseract`, and I wouldnt even know where and how to start.

This user repository is what I am using but doesnt work too well for what I want...

https://github.com/DivyaKrishnani/Working-with-Text-on-Images

Comment: Have you checked out [findContours](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html)?

Comment: @DrBwts working with the contours I have achieved the part of the frame cropped. But still difficult to detect the dialog bubbles with this method because of the irregular sizes their can have. Thanks you btw

Answer (score -2):

I can think of the following methods:

1. You can run an OCR to detect Korean texts and their corresponding box. Then you can paint the whole bounding box with white colour to remove these Korean words. There are free OCR python libraries available like Pytesseract, Keras-OCR, easy OCR, EAST text detection. Paid ones by Microsoft Azure, Amazon and Google.
2. You can treat each character as an object and train an object detection module (EfficientDet or YOLO) to detect the same. You will get the bounding box and do the same steps as mentioned in previous point.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you are not sure if these methods work, please comment instead of posting this as an answer, you will have to earn the [appropriate pointsto make comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).